# Direct all requests to a function including those with parameters

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to redirect ALL of the requests to `http function.`

I could see that our function will be called for every `example.com/someID` request, but will **not** for `example.com/folder1/someID`. That's because we have a folder named `folder1` which ignores the redirect rule, but we don't have `someID` folder so it listens to the rule(and call the function)

```
 exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
```

I would like to redirect *all* of our requests even if there is a path exist for that URL.

My firebase.json file looks like :

```
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "contentServer"
      }
    ],
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
  "headers": [ {
  "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
  "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value" : "*"
    } ]
  } ]

  },
```

***EDIT WITH CLARIFICATION***

I have a path like this `public/fodler1/index.html`, or  `public/fodler2/index.html.`

Usually when a user type `example.com/someID`, I return **from the function** `example.com/fodler1/?parm=1&parm=2` , or `example.com/fodler2/?parm=1&parm=2`, based on the `someID` variable.

Now, if a hacker do this to the returned url : `example.com/fodler1/?parm=fake!` , I would like to know that by **redirecting this URL** also to the `function` and identify this. **But** because this `URL` has a path that exist already -  `example.com/fodler1/`, Firebase will *ignore* my redirect rule and serve client back the fake page with the fake parameters.
(unlike doing `example.com/SOMEID`, without folder1)

I can see in other websites that if you try to change a parameter, and refresh  -  they always request the server **again** which fix that - and that's what I want to get.

So, even that i have the folders pathes `1/2` , I would like to go to my function anyway.

**According to the docs the priority order is this:**

1. Reserved namespaces that begin with a /__/* path segment
2. Configured redirects
3. **Exact-match static content**
4. *Configured rewrites*

Which means because i have the exact match to a content ( folder exist) it will  not rewrite.

Comment: It's not clear to me the problem you're observing.  Could you edit the question to indicate what exactly you're trying that doesn't work the way you expect, and what it's doing that's different?  Are you seeing an error?  Something else?

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, I have edited my question please see the end, it's very important to me.

Comment: @DougStevenson so no answer for that ? i was trying for days to find a way to really rewrite ALL requests, but it won't work if there is a folder in that path.

Comment: @hkrlys any update?

Answer (score 0):

I can think on different scenarios:

**1. Move the validation to your modules**

You can consider move that logical process to your code.

I can think of the following:

- Instead of serving the files from the JSON file, you can send all the request to a single endpoint or function.

  - That function would map all the incoming requests and would send it to the proper module of your app.
- For instance, if the request you receive matches with "public/fodler1/*", you can validate that the actual file they're trying to call exists.

  - If it exists, you return it.
  - If not, you send an error.

**2. Customize your 404 response**

You can serve a [custom your 404 Not Found error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#404) when a user tries to access a page that doesn't exist.

Create a new file in your project's public directory, name it 404.html, then add your custom 404 Not Found content to the file.

Firebase Hosting will display the content of this custom 404.html page if a browser triggers a 404 Not Found error on your domain or subdomain.

**3. Use Regex to validate your files**

Use a Regex in your JSON to validate that the object(s) exist(s).

I think this is the least idea you should consider. This is because you should update your JSON every time a file gets uploaded, deleted, or renamed.

You can also normalize your files so all could match with a Regex to use in your JSON. However, this last idea might not be the best because we'd return to your original issue: If a hacker gets that Regex, the effort would be in vane.

I hope this is helpful.